# Is it possible to have a display framebuffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I want to display a 2D array of pixels directly to the screen. The pixel-data is not static and changes on user triggered event like a mousemove. I wish to have a display framebuffer to which I could write directly to the screen.

I have tried to create a texture with `glTexImage2D()`. I then render this texture to a QUAD. And then I update the texture with `glTexSubImage2D()` whenever a pixel is modified.

It works!

But this is not the efficient way I guess. The `glTexSubImage2D` copies whole array including the unmodified pixels back to the texture which is not good performance wise.

Is there any other way, like having a "display-framebuffer" to which I could write only the modified pixels and change will reflect on the screen.

Comment: The only thing you could do is call glTexSubImage2D multiple times with offsets to assign modified pixels. But I'm not sure if it "wins" any performance since you have to calculate which pixels have been modified. But it also depends on how many pixels were modified. If you want you can test this and then you can see which way is better in terms of perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

glBlitFramebuffer is what you want.
Copies a rectangular block of pixels from one frame buffer to another. Can stretch or compress, but doesn't go through shaders and whatnot.
You'll probably also need some combination of glBindFramebuffer, glFramebufferTexture, glReadBuffer to set up the source and destination.